# POST data to JavaScript include

Tags: javascript, html, post, include

You know the standard JavaScript include in HTML?

```
<script src="http://example.com/script.js"></script>
```

How can I post data to that `src`? Using AJAX or jQuery is probably not an option, unless you can get it to work cross-domain.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Is script.js not a static file?

Comment: Don't think you can POST stuff to it easily, but you can send GET parameters to it in a simple way. Why do you need POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't post data and retrieve the content cross domain.  It's a security issue.

You probably already realize this, but you can do GET requests by appending it to the url:

```
<script src="http://example.com/script.js?key=value&key2=value"></script>
```

You could also use a proxy to retrieve cross domain requests from a site.  This project looks promising: https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/

But it appears to also only support GET requests through yahoo's server.

The only viable option is create a php(other other sever languages) proxy that you could filter through.  It wouldn't be to difficult using php's `curl` API.  There are equivalents in other server scripting languages.

Comment: Just curious, why does retrieving the contents of a POST request pose more of a security issue than retrieving the contents of a GET request?

Comment: In reality they are both security threats, and you actually can't retrieve the contents of a GET request either.  You can only invoke remote scripts through script tags.  The github project I linked to has the ability/limitation of retrieving only GET requests because that is the limitations yahoo imposed on the api.  The github project is in fact a proxy through yahoos servers.  JSONP was created to workaround these security issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp using the script tag